# Repeating Randomness in Microsoft Access Reports?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-access, database, microsoft-office-2010

I have created a report in Microsoft Access which contains a text box. The text box has a simple expression in the control source to generate a random string of digits in a specific format. I need to replicate the exact string of digits in a second text box. That is the same random string of digits must exist in two text boxes. Setting the second text box to the first text box's `Text` property only resulted in an error and directly inserting in control source `=[RandomText1]` resulted in a new random string of digits being developed in text box two with the algorithm in text box one. What can I do to create a single set of random digits and show it in two text boxes in Microsoft access? I am using Access 2007-2010 (That's just what it says so I think its actually 2010).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with using the first text box.  But don't use the Text property, just simply use the name of the first text box in the Control Source for the second text box.  If your first text box is named `TextBox1` then the Control source for the second text box will be `=[TextBox1]`